# What disease is affecting this rosemary?

Tags: diagnosis, herbs

My rosemary has been looking like this since last summer. It's currently getting worse. New leafs (if it develops any) soon have these white little spots on it.

What disease is this? Maybe false mildew?

What would be a good treatment for this?

[image]

Edit: In a first version of this post, I said the plant was a thyme, but it's a rosemary of course.

Comment: Agree, Rosemary, and Rosemary does not do well indoors - its an outdoors plant, so if your plants have been inside all winter, that is likely the cause of the troubles you're seeing. Cut back to healthy growth and move outdoors, hardening off first.

Comment: This seems an overwater issue. Put it outside in the sunlight if possible.